# PhpStorm save collapsed code blocks?

Tags: phpstorm

If I collapse a block of code using the +/- button, is there anyway that state can be saved for when I return to the file later? Currently all collapsed blocks are expanded again when I reload them.

(I'm using PhpStorm 9.0.2).

Comment: Dunno. Works for me -- blocks remain as long as that file was still opened when I was closing IDE/project. If file is closed at that point then yes, it looses such info after restart. **P.S.** You should also try the latest version -- there were some improvements in this area (not sure which ones exactly though).

Comment: Sorry, not sure I get you. If you leave the file open within the IDE and close Storm, when you reopen does the file still have the block folded?

Comment: Well .. that's how it works for me (php, xml files at least). But too say the truth sometimes it loses this folding between restarts -- I have no idea what's causing it. But it happens so rarely that I personally do not really care about it (I'm not relying on folding much). BTW -- what languages/files we are talking about here? In PHP/JS (at least) you can create custom folding blocks that can have default collapsed/expanded state.

Comment: Ah.. think I'm getting somewhere now. I mainly need it for HTML (because of all the block I have), I can't get it to work though even using the custom folding tags <editor-fold.... I tried it on a PHP file and that did work! I think you're right, I need to update to the latest version and ask support.

Comment: Try PhpStorm [v11 EAP build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/02/phpstorm-11-eap-145-61/) (v11 final should be released soon -- this month AFAIK) -- it definitely has improvements in folding (possibly different aspects of it, but still worth checking out)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93649 I guess (for custom blocks for XML/HTML code)

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually specific what do you want to collapse or no when you enter in a file with PHPStorm.

The name of this option in PHPStorm is : "**Code Folding**"
You can access this option in : PHPStorm > Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding.

You must specified what type code you want to collapse (if option no check then no collapse).

Now when you enter in a file with PHPStorm all the file collapse/folding/unfolding are the same.

You can refer to this : [Code Folding PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/code-folding-2.html)
or this : [AutoFolding behaviour PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-autofolding-behavior.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this allows me to fold on a construct level, but I wanted storm to remember only the blocks that I chosen to fold.